# Disable jScrollPanel veritcal scrollbar that appears in safari, chrome and opera but doesn't in Firefox

Tags: jquery, animation, cross-browser, jquery-jscrollpane

I have just recently upgrade my site to use the new jScrollPane v2. I have managed to customize it how I want it but today I was trying to add in a new feature between the photos which is a panel that on mouse over slides open to reveal text and on mouse off it collapse back again. In firefox this works OK but in Safari, Chrome and Opera, it creates a vertical scroll bar matching the look of my custom scroll bar and adds an 'arrow button. Am a bit of a novice when it comes to jquery and are learning as i go.

1st - I would like to know how to fix this across the browsers.
2nd - would like to know how to then make the text align to the bottom - I thought that I could control that with css but it doesn't seem to respond. Not sure if using lists is the best way to treat all the photos and text expander in the content holder.
3rd - I am referencing a lot of JavaScript files and wondered what is the best way to handle these as I am worry that my site will slow down.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have just noticed that the horizontal scroll bar is completely disabled in Safari, Chrome and Opera and I bet it doesn't work in IE either!  It is also trying to add the vertical scroll bar which I don't want to see.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `position:absolute` from `.jsPane` then it should work.

Comment: Thanks for for that - that has stop my red expander from scroll vertically in safari and chrome but not opera. Also in Safari, Chrome and Opera it still shows my custom vertical scroll bar and an arrow which is just a colour box a the end of the track line.